# Buffering block and filter length in real-time processing

Tags: filtering, real-time

I have a signal sampled at 256 Hz, which I want to filter with a 50 taps long FIR filter in real time. 
Would it be a problem, if my data block size is only 32 samples?
And should I then concatenate 3 blocks, convolve them with the filter and output only the middle part (to avoid discontinuities)?

And more general questions: were can I read more about all real-time aspects of time-series filtering? In particular about block processing?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data block can be as short as 1 sample (although longer is usually more efficient), as long as you save each full convolution response vector to overlap-add/sum into all the following output blocks.  Look up overlap-add/save fast convolution see how this can be done using an FFT/IFFT plus some add/save buffering.